# Assigning names of multiple selected workbooks to column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to select multiple files and have their names appear in a column in one main workbook.

My code runs but the filenames aren't showing up like I want.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FileNameExtraction()
    
    Dim filenames As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wbName As String
    Dim rngdest As Range
    
    Set rngdest = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1") '<< results start storing in this cell
    filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Excel Filter(*xlsx), *.xlsx", MultiSelect:=True)
    If TypeName(filenames) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub 'if nothing is selected, routine ends
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(filenames) 'i counts the files selected
        
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filenames(i))
        wbName = wb.Name
        wbName = rngdest.Value
        Set rngdest = rngdest.Offset(1, 0)
        
        wb.Close False 'closes workbook without saving changes
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the value of `wbName` without putting it into your sheet. You need to change `wbName = rngdest.Value` to `rngdest.Value = wbName`.

```
Sub FileNameExtraction()

Dim filenames As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Long
Dim wbName As String
Dim rngdest As Range

Set rngdest = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1") '<< results start storing in this cell
filenames = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
FileFilter:="Excel Filter(*xlsx), *.xlsx", MultiSelect:=True)
If TypeName(filenames) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub 'if nothing is selected, routine ends

For i = 1 To UBound(filenames) 'i counts the files selected

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filenames(i))
    wbName = wb.Name
    rngdest.Value = wbName '<== change here
    Set rngdest = rngdest.Offset(1, 0)

    wb.Close False 'closes workbook without saving changes

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I swear I tried that before... oh well, it's working great now! Thanks!